# How to resize an image in a UIButton while keeping the image's aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UIButton in a storyboard with an SFSymbol set as the button's image, and would like to make it bigger. I know I can change the alignment or make the image the button's background, but using either of those will cause the image to stretch to the button's width and height, and I would like to keep the original aspect ratio.

I have also tried setting `myButton.imageView.contentMode`, in the View Controller and setting the imageView's `preferredSymbolConfiguration`, but neither of these do anything - the icon on the button is still the same size as before.

Comment: Have you tried `UIButton.setPreferredSymbolConfiguration:forImageInState:` rather than setting it on the image view?

Answer (score 0):

set the image in background in image view

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably too late but for others arriving here from google like myself, here is how to change it right in the storyboard:

1. Select the button where you set the symbol as an image (not *background* image, just image)
2. Below that a new section will appear titled "Default Symbol Configuration", switch "Configuration" to "Point Size" and adjust the size as desired. I've found the "Font" option does not seem to work if there is no text specified on the button.

[image: Point size setting]

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand from the question, you are trying to make the image of the button bigger is that correct? Have you tried to create it in to an image instead and then giving that image a command when pressed? Check out the following code:

```
Image(systemName: "cloud.heavyrain.fill")   //Apple's San Francisvo Symbol Set to get predefined symbols
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .font(.headline)
    }
```

Here changing the font type changes the size of the image. Let me know if you have any questions but this should answer the question.

Comment: It's not a SwiftUI question.

Comment: I’m using UIKIt, not SwiftUI